# resizing and fitting an image to a parent div in react

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

Hi all I am new to react. I am building a site and have most of it done however I have run into a problem. I would like to write code within my scss folder such that a div element is declared with a given size and height and then a child element of this div is declared, so that calling the divs on an image will resized and centered to fit the width and heigh of the parent div. so the parent div specifies the size, the child element resizes and centers the image, and we can call the child element on any image we want on the site to resize and center the image to the dimensions of the parent div.

I tried something like

```
.container {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 115px;
    height: 115px;
    line-height: 115px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.resize_fit_center {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and then calling from a file named '_other.scss'

I did

```
<div class='container'>
    <a href='#'>
    <img class='resize_fit_center'
      src='http://i.imgur.com/H9lpVkZ.jpg' />
    </a>
</div>
```

but this did not work, specially if the images were within other pre-specified larger containers. any ideas of how to go about making a standard file in "scss" and calling it on images so that when it is applied the images can be resized and centered to the size of the parent div?

Answer (score 0):

The image was centered as you wish. But why do you limit the width of the container ?

```
.container {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 115px; // <== remove this line, you will see the image had been centered already.
    height: 115px;
    line-height: 115px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.resize_fit_center {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[Here is the demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-dhawan-5741k?file=/src/styles.css)

Comment: Hi I limited the container width because I want the container size to be constant. I want the image to center and rescale on a constant sized container no matter the image. If we remove that line, the container expands differently, as seen in your example. I am going to use these elements for many images, and I want them all to be in the same sized container

Comment: @lambdaepsilon I understand, so you need to center the container, not the image ^^.